# cx_Oracle config dsn

Tags: python, oracle-apex, cx-oracle

I want to connect to an Oracle Apex table via Python to update the table and insert new data, what must I enter for the dsn parameter, if my workspace is under:

```
https://apex.oracle.com/pls/apex/r/meteor_sdr

import cx_Oracle
# Establish the database connection
connection = cx_Oracle.connect(user="hr", password=userpwd,
                           dsn="dbhost.example.com/orclpdb1")
```

Comment: You cannot connect directly to the database in apex.oracle.com. The way to do this is to create a restful service in your workspace and post to that.

Comment: If the table is a just a data table you could connect to the DB and access it like any other table.  This may or may not be advisable, depending how the Apex app uses that table.  Without knowing more about how you connect, I can't suggest a dsn.  If you go down this route, I suggest using the latest version of cx_Oracle, which is now called python-oracledb. See the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a)